# Angular 5 - Cannot resolve observable in Observable.catch()

Tags: rxjs, angular2-observables, angular5

My first time here, I hope that you can help me.

I'm trying to create a response interceptor on Angular 5. I want to handle responses with status [202] successfully.

I'm doing a call to a webservice, the interceptor is working well it catches the error. If I return Observable.throw('') this will arrive to the error function on subscribe, but when I try to return a new Observable to resolve the exception, it is not arriving on success method of subscribe.

The interceptor code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, 
HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class Handle2xxResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
 Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   return next.handle(req).catch(error => {
     if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
       if (error.status === 202) {
        return Observable.of(error); // or return Observable.empty();
       }
     }
     return Observable.throw(error);
   });
 }
}
```

Thank you people.

Answer (score 3):

You're not able to catch 202 because 202 isn't an http error code and catch only catches errors.  Instead, just use a normal map or do operator or higher order operator like switchMap to do whatever you want with it:

```
return next.handle(req).switchMap(response => {
  if (response.status === 202) {
    // process error
    return Observable.empty();
  }
  return Observable.of(response);
});
```

Comment: Hi @bryan60. 
Thank you in advance.
In this case the status code 202 is considered as error, because the backend is not sending a body.

Comment: Anyway what is the best way to resolve an observable with success into the catch operation? It seems that when I try to return a new observable, the previous chain was already broken.

Comment: the presence or lack of a body isn't relevant to it being interpreted as an error or not.  The status code is what matters. 202 indicates that your request was accepted, and carries no requirement of including a body.

Comment: Angular interprets the range 200-299 as non error responses.

Comment: If you're saying that angular is throwing an error because you're using httpclient and you've told it to expect a json response, but the response body is actually non json, then the issue is that your error isn't actually an http error, it's a runtime error with no status, and you're not making it into the block that detects http errors and a status.  Simply logging the response should clear up what's going on.  You probably should build your service to expect the correct response type though. you can use the option parameter to either observe the entire response or set it to expect text.